# getting a method as a json data in angularjs and how to use it in html view

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have been working on an ui chart that takes data from my json and show it.. my json file is job.json this is the demo link but its hardcoded i want it to be dynamic getting data from database as json [link](http://designmind.in/projects/ramco/dashboard/dashboard.html)

```js
{
        "days": [{
          "dayname": "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
          "date": "2015-08-23",
          "hours": "hoursArray()"
        }, {
          "dayname": "Mon,24 Aug 2015",
          "date": "2015-08-24",
          "hours": "hoursArray()"
        }, {
          "dayname": "Tue,25 Aug 2015",
          "date": "2015-08-25",
          "hours": "hoursArray()"
        }, {
          "dayname": "Wed,26 Aug 2015",
          "date": "2015-08-26",
          "hours": "hoursArray()"
        }]
```

in which hoursarray() is a method but while using it in my code as an expression its not giving any result as when i was giving hardcoded value in angularjs controller. so please if you could tell me how to pass a hoursarray() method in my angularjs

the code for my angularjs file is

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myDashboardApp", []);
var array24 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23];
myApp.controller("mainController", function($scope,$http) {
 
  $http.get("job.json")
  .success(function(response) {
$scope.big = response;
});
 
 $scope.addition = function(index, add) {
  return Number(index) + Number(add);
 };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#scheduleApp").schedule();
});
function hoursArray(from) {
 var output = [];
 for (var i in from) {
  output.push(zeropreffix(i));
 }
 return output;
}

function zeropreffix(i) {
 return (String(i).match(/^[0-9]$/)) ? "0" + i : i;
}

function flightTime( hours) {
 var output = [];
 for (var i in hours) {
  if (i != 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
   output.push({
    breakhours : {
     station : "COK"
    }
   });
  } else {
   output.push({
    timing : {
     real : {
      start : zeropreffix(i) + ":00",
      end : zeropreffix(i) + ":59",
      code : "EK531"
     },
     actual : {
      start : zeropreffix(i) + ":00",
      end : zeropreffix(i) + ":59",
      code : "EK531"
     }
    }
   });
  }

 }
 return output;
```

this is my html file

```
                                        <div class="schedule-row border-t-dark-blue-fade">
                                            *<span class="schedule-cell schedule-hours" ng-repeat="hour in dayitem.hours" data-col-hours="{{hours}}"> {{hour}} </span>*
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Too much html...only post what is needed to represent the problem which for this would likely be just one ng-repeat. What you can do with the full code is put it into [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) as a demo for people to fork and test with.

Comment: It's hard to look through here and find the exact use but 2 things need to happen. You need to assign the function to a scope variable. `$scope.hoursArray = hoursArray`. But since the function requires a parameter to be passed in, that parameter variable doesn't exist in the string. That means `from` will be undefined.

Comment: also the jQuery code should be in a directive. if you use any routing the element it is looking for won't exist on page load

Comment: yes that,s why how to do it in a alternative way so that i can pass hours in a scope and it get the value from function hoursArray()

Comment: a jquery file is used called schedule.js

Comment: the jQuery plugin is fine. Just call that plugin inside a directive that is on the element it refers to. Is really uite easy ...inside `link` of a directive would be `element.schedule()`

Comment: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/xCYPsBQgiRxgBY4hZKNq?p=catalogue) here you can see the jquery file

Comment: [link](http://designmind.in/projects/ramco/dashboard/dashboard.html) 
this is what i need but they have used hardcoded values and i have to get this data from database as json file

Comment: done now i am having problem with hoursArray()

Comment: is `hoursArray` just for display? If so could turn it into angular filter. In the html `filter` can easily be represented as variables without `()` and arguments also using `:`

Comment: in hoursArray() function the code is passing an array24 which is returning an array of output and assign it to hours variable in days object

Comment: am still a bit confused why it needs to be string in json...will there be different function names `hoursArray()` & `anotherHoursArray()` ? If it is always the same would be easy to update the data in service when it arrives, before it gets to the view

Comment: actually i think i found the problem i was using $http in angular to get a local file so i was not able to get the json data can you please suggest me some method to get json data from a local file

Comment: `local file`? Are you not using a localhost server?

Comment: actually the problem is $http.get is calling the data asynchronously so before the response is coming the next step is performed without receiving data so it is giving error is there some synchronous method to get json data??

Comment: no...that is how ajax works. Will there be any routing in your app? If so can use `resolve` in routing config. Otherwise do all initialization inside the success callback

Comment: routing is not used in app but there is no method in angular or jquery that can call in synchronous way

Comment: no... but you could broadcast event for example to initialize plugin in directive if that's one of the issues. Or manually bootstrap angular after making your own request

Comment: how about if i use a service for calling the data?

Comment: or can i use two diffrent controller fro calling data and then assigning data into  $scope from other controller